# How to store large columnar text+numeric data in Python?

Tags: pandas, pickle, blaze

To save on disk without building columnar DB, there are :

```
SQLLite, 
HDFS5 : only numeric/fixed string
pickle serialization    
csv
csv compressed.
....
```

Just wondering which one is most efficient in term of speed ?
Thanks

Comment: saving text columns might be tricky... what would be the maximum length of your string values?

Comment: 300 Character (to make easy).

Comment: I'd consider Feather and HDF5, MySQL or PostgreSQL - might also be an option depending on how you are going to query your data ...

Comment: HDF5 cannot store well string... I think

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider Feather, HDF5. MySQL or PostgreSQL - might also be an option depending on how you are going to query your data...

Here is demo for HDF5:

```
In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10**6, (10**4, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [34]: df['txt'] = 'X' * 300

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
           a       b       c                                                txt
0     689347  129498  770470  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
1     954132   97912  783288  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
2      40548  938326  861212  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
3     869895   39293  242473  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
4     938918  487643  362942  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
...

In [37]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_str.h5', 'test', format='t', data_columns=['a', 'c'])

In [38]: store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/test_str.h5')

In [39]: store.get_storer('test').table
Out[39]:
/test/table (Table(10000,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Int32Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": StringCol(itemsize=300, shape=(1,), dflt=b'', pos=2),  # <---- NOTE
  "a": Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
  "c": Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=4)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (204,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "a": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "c": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it.
But, HDF5 suffers of corruption when interrupted.

So, am moving to zip file managers with blaze coupled.